# convert feedback comments rtl or ltr depending on language

Tags: alignment, arabic

I have a php feedback form that I want the comment text to be aligned to left or right depending on language:
if Arabic should be aligned rtl, any other language no (default which is ltr)

This is the current code line (that makes everything right to left!):

```
$comment = "<p dir=\"rtl\">".str_replace ("\n", "<br />", $comment);
```

so I want to tell it: if Arabic, then rtl, if not Arabic, ignore that rtl

Answer (score 1):

```
function containsArabic($str)
{
    return preg_match('~\p{Arabic}~u', $str);
}

echo containsArabic('helloسلام'); //  rturn 1
echo containsArabic('سلام');//return 1
echo containsArabic('testسلامtest'); // return 1
echo containsArabic('test');// return 0
```

if the text contain Arabic letter the function return 1 else return 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use [these regex'es](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072138/difference-between-php-regex-and-javascript-regex) to determine whether the comments contain Arabic or Persian chars.

```
function containsArabic($str)
{
    return preg_match('~\p{Arabic}~u', $str);
}

echo containsArabic('helloسلام');
echo containsArabic('سلام');
echo containsArabic('testسلامtest');
echo containsArabic('test');
```

Comment: thanks for the reply..  however I am new to this.. can you tell me what should I add to the above code to make it work?

Comment: I've edited the answer: http://ideone.com/5zFPC, just test your input and set the dir based on that.