# Allow additional special characters in a regex

Tags: php, regex

I would like to validate true for the following URLs.

```
$a = '/foo-bar-tar';
$b = '/foo-&-tar2';
$a = '/foo-bar-tar.';
$a = '/foo-bar.[tar]';
$a = '/foo-bar-tar';
```

All in all, these are the characters I am willing to accept, in no special order:

```
/ - & [  ]  ( ) .
```

And of course letters and numbers:

```
a-z A-Z 0-9
```

The problem is that I can validate letters, numbers, and special characters like `/.-`, but I am having trouble validating `()[]` – I guess because these are part of the regex language.

Here is the pattern I have so far:

```
^(/[a-z-A-z-0-9.]+)$
```

It matches letters, numbers, and `.`, but I don't know how to make it work for `()[]`.

Comment: Suggest that you read about __escaping__ "special characters" in regular expressions - http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following adaptation of the pattern instead:

```
^\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-&\[\]().]+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/VX9w1lWQKO0oWa7N) (with unit tests for all the sample input strings in the question)

Key points:

- `^` – matches the start of the input string
- `\/` – the opening `/` you expect
- `[a-zA-Z0-9\-&\[\]().]+` – one or more (`+`) alphanumeric (`a-zA-Z0-9`) or allowed special characters (`\-&\[\]().`) with `-`, `[`, and `]` escaped in the character class due to their special meaning in that context
- `$` – matches the end of the input string

Also, I did not retain the grouping parens (i.e. `(` and `)`) because they make little sense with the pattern constrained by `^` and `$` and only one match of interest (i.e. the whole input string).

Comment: Hi, sorry. I thought Js and PHP regex was the same. Does this actually work on JS? I mean in stored as a Json?

Comment: Much of what you can do with regexes will be the same in PHP and JS, but there are differences.  For more info, I defer to a [related SO answer on the differences between regexes in PHP and JS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9072234/1810429).